# Find the maximum value of $\det(M)+ \det(N)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

$M,N $ are two $4\times 4 $ matrices satisfying, 
$$
MN=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
   0 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
I have no idea how to approach this problem, help will be appreciated.

Find the maximum value of $\det(M)+ \det(N)$

Comment: What did you try? Do you know the properties of determinants and the methods of finding maxima/minima using calculus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**$$\bigl(\forall x\in(0,\infty)\bigr):(x\operatorname{Id}).\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{x} & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{x} \\ 0 & \frac{2}{x} & \frac{2}{x} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{x} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{x}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I wonder why do you choose $n$ to be integer? It should work with $n\in\mathbb R_+$ as well, should not it?

Comment: @user For no good reason. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: In your proof I like very much the explicit construction of both matrices (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = MN$ then we can calculate the minimum value, if $\det(M)>0$: $$\det (M)+\det (N) = \det(M)+{\det(A) \over \det(M)}\geq 2\sqrt{\det(A)} = 8$$

but there is no maximum value for $$\det(M)+{16 \over \det(M)}$$

Just draw a function $f(x) = x+{16\over x}$ where $x=\det(M)\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$